# iOSでFlutterのUTF-8をdecodeできない問題の解決方法

Tags: ios, flutter

Flutterを使ったiOSアプリ内でHTTPレスポンス(bodybyte)をUTF-8でデコードできない問題が発生しており、指導いただければ幸いです。
AndroidのPixel 2のエミュレータでは問題なくデコードできていたのでiOS特有の問題であると考えています。

以下のコードをiOS Deployment Target=9.0でPhone12 Pro Maxのエミュレータで実行した結果になります。
decoded_body_byteがnullになってしまう部分が問題になります。

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:charset_converter/charset_converter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_user_agent/flutter_user_agent.dart';
// skip

String userAgent;
try {
  userAgent = await FlutterUserAgent.getPropertyAsync('userAgent');
  print("userAgent: ${userAgent}");
} on PlatformException {
  userAgent = '<error>';
}
var response = await http.Client().get(Uri.parse("http://news4vip.livedoor.biz/archives/52385788.html"), headers: {'User-Agent': userAgent});
print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
print("response.headers: ${response.headers['content-type']}");
String decoded_body_byte = await CharsetConverter.decode("UTF-8", response.bodyBytes);
print("decoded_body_byte: ${decoded_body_byte}"); // ここの結果がnullになってしまうことが問題になっています。
Uint8List encoded = await CharsetConverter.encode("UTF-8", "【画像】中日「かっこいい」今季のユニホーム発表ｗｗｗ");
print("encoded.length: ${encoded.length}");
String decoded_body_byte_only_title = await CharsetConverter.decode("UTF-8", response.bodyBytes.sublist(71, 71 + 78));
print("decoded_body_byte_only_title: ${decoded_body_byte_only_title}");
```

以下は上コードの出力結果になります。

```
2021-01-23 17:09:29.964984+0900 Runner[89036:14458916] flutter: userAgent: CFNetwork/1209 Darwin/20.2.0 (iPhone iOS/14.3)
2021-01-23 17:09:30.187131+0900 Runner[89036:14458916] flutter: Response status: 200
2021-01-23 17:09:30.190547+0900 Runner[89036:14458916] flutter: response.headers: text/html; charset=utf-8
2021-01-23 17:09:30.195755+0900 Runner[89036:14458916] flutter: decoded_body_byte: null
2021-01-23 17:09:30.197368+0900 Runner[89036:14458916] flutter: encoded.length: 78
2021-01-23 17:09:30.198128+0900 Runner[89036:14458916] flutter: decoded_body_byte_only_title: 【画像】中日「かっこいい」今季のユニホーム発表ｗｗｗ
```

以下flutter doctorの出力結果になります。ご回答いただければ幸いです。

```
% flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale ja-JP)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: ご質問中のコードに記載されたURLをブラウザでアクセスしたところ`Content-Type` ヘッダの値は`text/html; charset=euc-jp`でした。エンコーディングに`"UTF-8"`ではなく、`"euc-jp"`を指定したらどうなりますか?

Comment: User-Agentを出力結果に表示されているものに入れ替えたら、`text/html; charset=utf-8`の結果が返ってくるようになりましたが。レスポンスにUTF-8としては不正なバイト列が含まれているようです。Dartの`CharsetConverter`がiOSの文字列処理を呼んでいるだけだとすると、このようなバイト列はデコードできない、と言うことになります。不正なバイト列を削除するか置換するかと言った前処理を置かないと、iOSではデコードできなさそうです。

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[Flutter(Dart) で Shift_JIS/EUC-JP をデコード](https://qiita.com/manymanyuni/items/771c6964de8a68493800)

Answer (score 2):

みなさまコメントありがとうございます。@OOPerさまの下記の推測が正しかったようです。

> UTF-8としては不正なバイト列が含まれている

CharsetConverterではSwiftのNSStringクラスを流用しているだけのようでした。

https://github.com/pr0gramista/charset_converter/blob/master/ios/Classes/SwiftCharsetConverterPlugin.swift#L49

そこでデコーダーを以下のPluginに変更した所、想定通りにデコードすることができました。

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/Utf8Codec/decode.html

```
String decoded = Utf8Decoder(allowMalformed: true).convert(response.bodyBytes);
```

※ `allowMalformed: true` がUTF8の不正文字を置換してくれるようです。

大変助かりました、ありがとうございます。